# Rope not following curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I'm making a model for a school project and I'm trying to make a industrial revolution machine but my rope won't follow the curve properly heres the rope I'm trying to get it connect on the other side [image]

Comment: attach your file

Comment: Hi, it is difficult to guide you to solve without having your file, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question, and paste the providced link.

Comment: @atek 2500 points are more than enough for you to know that you should suggest the above link when you ask file, in particular with new users...

Comment: A few things to check: 1- Did you apply scale to the curve and the rope? (In the posted image the scale is not 1) 2- Are the origins for the rope and the curve in the same place?